# Problem when scrolling ScrollView control?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, scrollview

I have a problem with my `UIScrollView`. It's visible but I can't scroll it.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(20, 90,280,1000);
scroll1=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
scroll1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(280,1000);
scroll1.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];

//scroll1.delegate=scroll1;
[scroll1 setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
[scroll1 setPagingEnabled:TRUE];
[scroll1 setScrollEnabled:TRUE];
[scroll1 showsVerticalScrollIndicator];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the frame to the same width and height as the content.
Try a smaller frame like (20, 90, 200, 300).

Comment: thank you Dyingcactus..
after i submit question i got th answer...
i implement it that way only....
thanks again